# Pandas accumulation without for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a pandas frame work like:

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
```

And the output is something like

```
1. 1
2. 3         
3. 6         
4. 10
```

where each value is the current value plus the last one (3 = 1 + 2, 6 = 3 + 3, 10 = 6 + 4 etc).

Can I do this without a for loop?

Comment: [`pd.DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) is what you're looking for

Comment: @M.Klugerford That will do it. Thanks. Btw for each value, does cumsum() sum all the values up before that? If so it could be not very efficient right? Is there a way to keep updating the previous value and add it by the current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df)
     col
1.0    1
2.0    2
3.0    3
4.0    4

df['col1'] = df.col.cumsum()
print (df)
     col  col1
1.0    1     1
2.0    2     3
3.0    3     6
4.0    4    10
```

If need overwrite column `col`:

```
df.col = df.col.cumsum()
print (df)
     col
1.0    1
2.0    3
3.0    6
4.0   10
```

Comment: Thanks man. cumsum() will do the trick. Now I wonder if there is a way I can update each value while calculating so for next value, instead of adding up all the previous values, I can just add it by the last updated value?

Comment: So output is only `10`?

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: The output are all the values, not just 10

Comment: Hmmm, if need something fast the best is use native pandas functions like `cumsum`. So I think it is possible, but slowier and less effective as `cumsum.`

Comment: Ok. I was worrying about the efficiency. That's actually why I asked this question. Thank you Jezrael!